# Powerpc -msecure-plt verification

Tags: powerpc, plt

I am trying to compile with -msecure-plt, and although compilation is completing just fine, when looking at the memory maps it doesn't look like the flag is actually doing anything. I am assuming it is not doing anything because the got and plt sections are both still in `RWXP` segements.

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x1000061c <+0>:     stwu    r1,-16(r1)
0x10000620 <+4>:     mflr    r0
0x10000624 <+8>:     stw     r0,20(r1)
0x10000628 <+12>:    stw     r31,12(r1)
0x1000062c <+16>:    mr      r31,r1
0x10000630 <+20>:    bl      0x1001096c <libfunc@plt>
0x10000634 <+24>:    mr      r10,r3
0x10000638 <+28>:    lis     r9,4096
0x1000063c <+32>:    addi    r3,r9,2048
0x10000640 <+36>:    mr      r4,r10
0x10000644 <+40>:    crclr   4*cr1+eq
0x10000648 <+44>:    bl      0x10010964 <printf@plt>
=> 0x1000064c <+48>:    li      r9,1
0x10000650 <+52>:    mr      r3,r9
0x10000654 <+56>:    addi    r11,r31,16
0x10000658 <+60>:    lwz     r0,4(r11)
0x1000065c <+64>:    mtlr    r0
0x10000660 <+68>:    lwz     r31,-4(r11)
0x10000664 <+72>:    mr      r1,r11
0x10000668 <+76>:    blr
```

with `/proc/<pid>/maps` showing a memory map of

```
00100000-00103000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
0fe40000-0ffb8000 r-xp 00000000 00:01 6285       /lib/libc-2.22.so
0ffb8000-0ffc7000 ---p 00178000 00:01 6285       /lib/libc-2.22.so
0ffc7000-0ffc9000 r--p 00177000 00:01 6285       /lib/libc-2.22.so
0ffc9000-0ffcd000 rwxp 00179000 00:01 6285       /lib/libc-2.22.so
0ffcd000-0ffcf000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
0ffdf000-0ffe0000 r-xp 00000000 00:01 5928       /lib/libmaintest.so
0ffe0000-0ffef000 ---p 00001000 00:01 5928       /lib/libmaintest.so
0ffef000-0fff0000 rwxp 00000000 00:01 5928       /lib/libmaintest.so
10000000-10001000 r-xp 00000000 00:01 5934       /root/main
10010000-10011000 rwxp 00000000 00:01 5934       /root/main
b7860000-b7882000 r-xp 00000000 00:01 6240       /lib/ld-2.22.so
b7890000-b7892000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7892000-b7893000 r--p 00022000 00:01 6240       /lib/ld-2.22.so
b7893000-b7895000 rwxp 00023000 00:01 6240       /lib/ld-2.22.so
bff1a000-bff3b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

which sticks both of the plot jumps right into the middle of a `rwx` section. Am I misinterpreting this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that might be a kernel limitation: see e.g. https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/8/8/354 - it looks like the kernel maps things in ways you wouldn't expect for what I understand to be historical reasons.

It may be changing soon, given that the patch above was sent yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of gcc, the `-msecure-plt` flag might be ignored if any libraries you linked to were not also compiled with `-msecure-plt` (including `glibc`). See [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-10/msg01783.html).